# JavaScript not working in Android TV webview

Tags: android, android-tv

JS works fine in webview on mobie device but not working on television (Tested with v10 and v11 android). Any way to enable it?

**XML**

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BrowserActivity"
    android:id="@+id/webView1" >
```

**Java**

```
WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
wb.loadUrl("https://MySiteWithJS.com/");
```

Comment: Any errors you are seeing in the console/logs?

Comment: no errors. used chrome://inspect to inspect te vebview but no js command works in console